# Select columns in a DataFrame conditional on row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am attempting to generate a dataframe (or series) based on another dataframe, selecting a different column from the first frame dependent on the row using another series. In the below simplified example, I want the frame1 values from 'a' for the first three rows, and 'b for the final two (the picked_values series).

```
frame1=pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10).reshape(5,2),index=range(5),columns=['a','b'])
picked_values=pd.Series(['a','a','a','b','b'])
```

Frame1

```
    a           b
0   0.283519    1.462209
1   -0.352342   1.254098
2   0.731701    0.236017
3   0.022217    -1.469342
4   0.386000    -0.706614
```

Trying to get to the series:

```
0   0.283519
1   -0.352342
2   0.731701
3   -1.469342
4   -0.706614
```

I was hoping `values[picked_values]` would work, but this ends up with five columns.

In the real-life example, picked_values is a lot larger and calculated.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`df.lookup`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.lookup.html)

```
pd.Series(frame1.lookup(picked_values.index,picked_values))
```

---

```
0    0.283519
1   -0.352342
2    0.731701
3   -1.469342
4   -0.706614
dtype: float64
```

Comment: And this is why stack overflow is the best. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Here's a `NumPy` based approach using [`integer indexing`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html) and [`Series.searchsorted`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.searchsorted.html):

```
frame1.values[frame1.index, frame1.columns.searchsorted(picked_values.values)]
# array([0.22095278, 0.86200616, 1.88047197, 0.49816937, 0.10962954])
```

Comment: I was wondering why this has a different output, then realized that the sample is a random.

Comment: Yup :) could've stuck to the generated one to make it less confusing @anky